# Proof of Stone's generalization of Weierstrass theorem in PMA by Walter Rudin

Tags: analysis, weierstrass-approximation

I was going through a proof of Stone's generalization of Weierstrass theorem in the book PMA by Walter Rudin. The theorem is stated as such:

> **Theorem 7.32**  Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra of real continuous functions on a compact set $K$. If  $\mathscr{A}$ separates points on $K$ and if $\mathscr{A}$ vanishes at no point of $K$, then the **uniform closure** $\mathscr{B}$ of $\mathscr{A}$ consists of all real continuous functions on $K$.

The algebra has been defined in the book as

> A family $\mathscr{A}$ of complex functions defined on a set $E$ is said to be an ***algebra*** if $$\begin{align} & a)\qquad f+g\in\mathscr{A}\\ & b)\qquad fg \in \mathscr{A}\\ & c)\qquad cf \in \mathscr{A} \end{align}$$ for all $f\in\mathscr{A},g\in \mathscr{A}$ and for all complex constants $c$

The uniform closure has been defined as

> Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of all functions which are limits of uniformly convergent sequences of members of $\mathscr{A}$. Then $\mathscr{B}$ is called the ***uniform closure*** of $\mathscr{A}$.

The above Theorem 7.32 has been proved in 4 steps in the book and I have a doubt in STEP 3

> $\mathtt{STEP\space 1}\qquad$ if $f\in\mathscr{B}$, then $\space|f|\in\mathscr{B}$

> $\mathtt{STEP\space 2}\qquad$ if $f\in\mathscr{B}$ and $g\in\mathscr{B}$, then $\space max(f,g)\in\mathscr{B}$ and $\space min(f,g)\in\mathscr{B}$

> $\mathtt{STEP\space 3}\qquad$ Given a real function $f$, continuous on $K$, a point $x\in K$ and $\varepsilon>0$ , there exists a function $g_x \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $ g_x(x)=f(x)$ and $$g_x(t) \gt f(t)-\varepsilon \qquad (t\in K)$$

In the proof of $\mathtt{STEP\space 3}$ it starts with the statement

> Since $\mathscr{A}\subset \mathscr{B}\space$...

Now my question is why is $\mathscr{A}\subset\mathscr{B}\space$? Is it always true that an ***algebra*** is a subset of its ***uniform closure***, if not then why is it true in this case?

Comment: What is the the limit of a constant sequence $\{f,f,...\}$?

Comment: But such functional sequence will always be uniformly convergent to itself? So, you're saying that $\mathscr{B}$ will contain all the functions of $\mathscr{A}$ simply because every function of $\mathscr{A}$ can form a constant sequence which is uniformly convergent to itself?

Comment: Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ such that $f_n = f$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. 

For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N=1$; then $n \ge 1 \,\Rightarrow\, |f_n(x) - f(x)| = |f(x) - f(x)| = 0 < \epsilon$ for all $x \in K$. Thus, $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $K$.